# Get 3 URLs from XML, randomly select one to save to variable

Tags: php, xml, tumblr

I'm in over my head at this point - but what i have currently looks like this:

```
<?php
    $request_url = "http://aethereverywhere.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo&tagged=ae&start=0&num=1";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    $img = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'};
?>
```

If increase &num to 3, lets say - it'll pull three files, and simplexml_load_file will parse them out - and save them to $img - but what i'd like to is have only one URL saved to $img, selected at random.

Thanks for the help

Comment: if you start at a random number and limit to 1 will that work for you

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the v1 API?

Comment: I'm using the v1 API because it was the one that i could get my head around - i wasn't having any luck with v2 unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New code: select a random image from 0 to 118 (total 119), then outputing, choose the highest resolution.

```
<?php
    $request_url = "http://aethereverywhere.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo&start=".rand(0,118);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    $img = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'};
    $img=(array)$img;

    echo '<img src="'.$img[0].'">';
?>
```

Comment: This is making more sense to me - but doesn't work: even though i've set num=20 it's only returning the same single URL everytime - i think it may have to do with simplexml_load_file not accepting more than a single post at a time?

Comment: Are you on a shared web hosting? `simplexml_load_file` is probably blocked, this works fine on my local machine.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message - it is parsing and displaying a URL, but it's the same one everytime.

Comment: All the urls are very similar, they all start with `http://25.media.tumblr.com/9dacd072c8716f8674900c292669c7ff/tumblr_mkfi5rjsoo1qmvy8zo1_` also when I change the `num=3` or `num=2` they still output the same set of images.

Comment: @user16111 The reason why you're getting the same one everytime is because there's only one photo post on that tumblr with the tag 'ae'.

Comment: That's because the original request is also sorting by "tagged=ae", there are only two posts tagged ae - if you remove that it should pull the max num.  I've gone ahead though and removed it and upon multiple refreshes its still only displaying the same single URL everytime. Are you getting different results than i am are you see randomization? Thanks for the help btw, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: How's that? If you want, there's a way to get how many posts there are, and you can get your random images based on that number.

Comment: I realized it was sorting by "ae" tagged posts - but that wasn't what was causing a lack of randomizing - even with the tag parameter removed and the num parameter increased to a larger number, (say 20) i'm still not seeing a random URL displayed, it's always the same URL.

Comment: I updated the code to show the image, it should be a different GIF every time.

Comment: I'm having a look at your new code - This works great, i guess as i go along continuing to add gifs if i have a total of say 220 gifs, but the random call still is set to 118, it'll pull from the 118 most recent?

Comment: This is great - thanks so much, great solution to use the "start" parameter. My code ended up looking like this: `$request_url = "http://aethereverywhere.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo&tagged=ae&start=".rand(0,5);`- you can view the results at www.aethereverywhere.com - just a personal project.

Comment: There's 119 in total, if you try to get an image from `num=119`, it won't return a set of images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29457/discussion-between-dave-chen-and-user16111)

Answer (score 0):

Add a random number between 0 and the total photos -1. ie, get it in one line randomly.

```
$img = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'}[$random] // if that's the right syntax.
```

Or while iterating through the tags, do a random check for an even/odd number.

```
$img = (empty($img) || !$img) ? (rand(10)%2==0) ? $PHOTO_URL : FALSE : $img;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - i'm unsure how to introduce a random number.

Comment: Check out - http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php . It's syntax is fairly easy - rand($min,$max). Make the $min = 0 and $max = total photo-url tags - 1

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x, or use simplexml_load_file
$urls = $xml->xpath("//photo-url"); // get all <photo-url> nodes

echo $urls[rand(0,count($urls)-1)]; // echo a random url
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WDq0ha